# Is it possible to convert timestamps to miliseconds with Python?

Tags: python, timestamp

**For example i have an array with some timestamps:**

```
    14:34:56.600

    14 = hour
    34 = minute
    56 = seconds
    600 = milliseconds
```

After the conversion I want to have a single number in milliseconds. Is this possible?

Comment: Can I assume you have an array of datetime.time() objects?

Comment: Actually my array has strings.

Comment: I want to iterate and convert a column of strings of the above format as a column of milliseconds

Comment: What's the problem in performing a little set of simple multiplications?

Comment: No prob, Just confused. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get the job done:

```
def toMS(t):
    t = t.split(':')
    t = t[:-1] + t[-1].split('.')
    t = list(map(int, t))
    ms = t[0]*3600*1000 + t[1]*60*1000 + t[2]*1000 + t[3]
    return ms
```

Comment: it worked. Thank you. Now i will iterate with this in a table to get ms